# Unsure of how to complete this task using subclasses and superclasses in python

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

The task is to define a class named 'Shape' and its subclass 'Square'. The Square class has an 'init' function which takes a given length as an argument. Both classes have an area function which can print the area of the shape, where Shape's area is 0 by default.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
class Shape:
    area = 0
    def __init__(self, ??):



class Square(Shape):

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def area(self):
        a = (self.length * self.length)
        print('The area of a square with a side length of %f is %f' % (self.length, a))


s = Square(2)
s.area()
```

I am unsure of what to do in the Shape superclass.

Comment: Looks to me like Shape should be an abstract class. If that's the case it can define the abstract area method, which you then provide an implementation for in subclasses.

Comment: I think it would be advisable to have a `print_area(self)` method in the super-class, which just prints the field area and to initialize it in the `__init__` method of the subclass and not have an overwritten function to print the area in the subclass.

Comment: _"Both classes have an area function"_ `area = 0` is not a function. You could start by fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to override the default function `area` in the `Shape` class. Then, when you have a list of shapes - some `Shape`, some `Square` and may be even some `Polygon`, you can print them all just by calling `area` without knowing which class it is. Polymorphism!

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def area(self):
        print(0)
```

It is also important to invoke constructor of the super class when creating an instance of the subclass. There may be some necessary initiation for the inner structure of the superclass:

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        super(Square, self).__init__()
```